# Chaining models relations in node.js (node-orm) like in Rails

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, node-orm2

I'm building a relatively big NodeJS application, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to fetch the data I need from the DB. Here is a part of my models :

One user has one role, which has access to many modules (where there's a table role_modules to link roles and modules).

In Rails, I would do something like user.role.modules to retrieve the list of the modules he has access to. In NodeJS it's a bit more complicated. I'm using [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) along with PostgreSQL. Here is what I have so far:

```
req.models.user.find({email: req.body.user}, function(err, user) {
  user[0].getRole(function(err, role) {
    role.getModules(function(err, modules) {
      var list_modules = Array();
      modules.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        list_modules.push(item.name);
      })
```

But I can't do this, because item only contains role_id and module_id. If I want to have the name, I would have to do `item.getModule(function() {...})`, but the results would be asynchronous ... so I don't really see how I could end up with an array containing the names of the modules a user has access to ... have any idea?

Also, isn't that much slower than actually running a single SQL query with many JOIN? Because as I see it, the ORM makes multiple queries to get the data I want here...

Thank you!

Comment: As i understood, you want to reach module from user, right? Have you try on association in `node-orm2` ?

Comment: Well yes, that's what I'm using, but even with that I'm not quite sure how I can end up with an array of module names from the user, when all requests are async... Also I'm not sure about the good performance of this VS a plain old JOIN chain in SQL

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an ORM called [bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org) that aims to simplify associations and eager loading relations between models in SQL. This is what your query would probably look like to load the role & modules on a user given your description:

```
var Module = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'modules'
});

var Role = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'roles',

  modules: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Module);
  }
});

var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users'

  role: function() {
    return this.hasOne(Role);
  }
});


User.forge({email: req.body.user})
  .fetch({
    require: true,
    withRelated: ['role.modules']
  })
  .then(function(user) {

    // user, now has the role and associated modules eager loaded
    console.log(user.related('role'));
    console.log(user.related('role').related('modules'))

  }, function(err) {

    // gets here if no user was found.

  });
```

Might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: Is it possible in Bookshelf to query with constraints on related data? i.e. fetch({ require: true, withRelated: ['role.modules'] }).where('role.modules.length', '>', '1') (pseudo-code :))